# Metodos que retornam valores constantes em C e C++ mesmo que oriundos de variáveis, é possível?

Tags: variáveis, c++11, constantes, imutabilidade

Numa série de otimizações em um código escrito em C++ adotei uma classe para armazenar dados de parametrização da aplicação e alguns pseuconstantes vamos dizer assim.

O que ocorre na verdade é que quando a aplicação inicializa ela obtém em um arquivo todos parâmetros e informações de renderização de janelas.

Há um determinado ponto na aplicação muito crítico que não deve levar mais que 30ms e que sequencialmente executado porque gera 30 frames por segundo no máximo. O que mais pesa neste código não é lidar com tais variáveis, mas não quero consumir os recursos com sua manipulação já que depois de carregadas do arquivo de configuração elas não mudarão.

Pensei em primeira mão em usar o diretiva volatile, mas não é o caso, pois não são variáveis nem constante que serão externamente alteradas por outras threads ou dispositivos externos.

Pensei em fazer um Casting durante a obtenção dos dados, porém como disse tais informações são obtidas com certa frequência não torna eficaz o uso do Casting.

Quase todas variáveis são do tipo std::string e inteiros.

A arquitetura usada é Cortex-A ARMv8 (Cortex-A53)

O compilador é o GCC 4.8.2 (linux).

Em resumo poderia dizer que fora desta classe todas os dados estarão como constantes, mas internamente elas são variáveis, quando esta classe é inicializada.

### Código fonte da classe config

Veja por exemplo a variável da função "fullWindowName", uma vez definida pela leitura do arquivo de configuração, nunca mais será alterada durante a execução.

https://gist.github.com/carlosdelfino/3d825370dcca03fea0db67cbe73c00b1

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dificuldade. Na verdade nem o que está fazendo e encontrando dificuldade concretamente. Pelo meu entendimento, e posso ter me enganado, isso não é possível e nem faz sentido.

Comment: É difícil responder uma pergunta assim sem um exemplo adequado. Você quer otimizar o acesso a uma variável ou algo assim? Entendi que o fato de ser carregado de um arquivo apenas impede declarar os valores no código para otimização durante a compilação, mas uma vez os valores carregados nas variáveis, o que mais precisa ser melhorado? Tudo o que consigo adiantar é que `volatile` não tem nada a ver com isso, serve apenas **impedir** otimizações, e que se há necessidade de fazer *cast* toda vez que acessa, é porque o tipo da variável provavelmente está declarado errado.

Comment: Essa pergunta carece de dados para ser respondida. Sem um exemplo claro não há o que ser feito. Manipular variáveis ou constantes deve levar exatamente o mesmo tempo, pois não passam de posições de memória. Isso mostra o quanto essa pergunta precisa de esclarecimento. Você já utilizou alguma ferramenta de verificação de performance para identificar em que ponto exato do código se dá a perda de rendimento? Normalmente programadores passam a maior parte do tempo otimizando partes do código que não precisariam.

Comment: Sem dúvida @Loudenvier, a optimização demanda muito tempo, quase tanto quanto planejamento leva em relação a execução de um projeto. No caso vou postar pergunta um Link para a classe config que uso atualmente, ela está gigante eu sei, são mais de 500 linhas em geral, e precisa ainda de muito ajuste.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, estou quase convicto que realmente não vai mudar muito os ajustes a tal ponto, mas por desencargo de consciência achei melhor perguntar.

Comment: @AndréSassi o grande problema do casting é que algumas funções por exemplo esperam std::string e outros esperam const char*, sendo o mesmo dado. é uma discrepância entre bibliotecas usadas.

Comment: Sobre o uso do Volatile, é comum em microcontroladores ou sistemas embarcados que acessam diretamente uma área de memoria e esta é apontada para uma variável que ela seja tratada como const volatile já que o hardware será responsável por atualiza-la, o código então deve compreender que ela será alterada externamente,

Comment: @Delfino, no caso de `std::string` para `const char*`, use o método `c_str` e o custo é nulo por ser `inline` (é apenas sintaxe do C++, não gera nenhuma instrução extra no código compilado). O `volatile` serve para *desativar* otimizações em relação à variável, e por isso é necessário para registradores de hardware, caso contrário o compilador jogaria fora ou reordenaria uso de variáveis aparentemente inúteis (por que ele não tem ciência do hardware), e isso parece não ter nenhuma relação com a pergunta. Por favor, coloque na pergunta um exemplo reduzido que deixe o seu problema evidente.